# Django in production (nginx, gunicorn, supervisor). Server Error (500) при отправке формы

Tags: python, django, nginx, vps, supervisor

**Доброго времени суток, товарищи программисты!**

Сделал проект на **Django** и залил его на хостинг **VPS** с помощью **nginx**, **gunicorn** и **supervisor**. Это моя первая практика.

Проблема заключается в том, что при отправке формы на сайте выходит ошибка **`Server Error (500)`**. Хотя сам сайт работает, и в админке всё тоже изменяется, добавляется и т.д.
Пробовал на локальном сервере на моём ПК и нет никакой ошибки (естественно с DUBUG=True).

### **Данные, которые могут быть полезны для решения проблемы:**

**Установленные модули python:**

```
django
django-adminlte3
Pillow
django-ipware
gunicorn
supervisor
DateTime

asgiref
pytz
sqlparse
zope.interface
```

**Упрощённый html формы (ну на всякий случай):**

```html
<form action="{% url 'send_email:send' %}" method="POST">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <div>
    <p>Ваше имя: </p>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Введите Ваше имя" name="name">
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Ваш номер телефона: </p>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Введите Ваш телефон" name="phone">
  </div>
  <button type="submit">Отправить</button>
</form>
```

**Код send_email views.py:**

```py
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from main.models import Email
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from .models import *
from ipware import get_client_ip
import datetime


def send(request):
    if request.method == "POST" and request.POST["name"] and request.POST["phone"]:
        client_ip = get_client_ip(request) # получаю ip отправителя
        name = request.POST["name"] # получаю имя отправителя через POST
        phone = request.POST["phone"] # получаю номер телефона отправителя через POST
        
        # обрезаю поля на всякий случай
        name = name[:255] 
        phone = phone[:255]

        # достаю email из БД, на который нужно отправлять письмо
        emails = Email.objects.all()
        if emails:
            to = emails[0]
        else: # если не сработало, то загружаю заявку в БД (default для email_to стоит)
            email_request = EmailRequest(
                ip_user=client_ip[0],
                name=name,
                phone=phone,
                request_time=f"{datetime.datetime.now()} (по времени сервера)"
            )
            email_request.save()

            return redirect('main:index') # перенаправление

        # формирую письмо
        message = f"""
                Кто-то отправил заявку
                Имя отправителя: {name};
                Номер телефона отправителя: {phone};"""

        html = f"""
                <html>
                <head></head>
                <body>
                    <h1>Кто-то отправил заявку</h1>
                    <h3>Имя отправителя: {name};</h3>
                    <h3>Номер телефона отправителя: <a href="tel:{phone}">{phone}</a>;</h3> 
                    <hr>
                    IP-адрес отправителя: {client_ip[0]}
                </body>
                </html>"""

        # отправка письма на почту
        send_mail(subject='Получена заявка от клиента', message=message, from_email=f"{settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL} <{settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER}>", recipient_list=[to], html_message=html)

        # загрузка заявки в БД
        email_request = EmailRequest(
            ip_user=client_ip[0],
            name=name,
            phone=phone,
            email_to=to,
            request_time=f"{datetime.datetime.now()} (по времени сервера)"
        )
        email_request.save()

        return redirect('main:index') # перенаправление
    else:
        return redirect('main:index')
```

Возможно, ошибка в настройках библиотеки send_mail.

**Вот основные настройки проекта:**

```py
DEBUG = False

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.dummy.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.mail.ru'
EMAIL_PORT = '25'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = '<EMAIL ADDRESS>'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '<PASSWORD>'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = '<NAME IN ENGLISH>'
EMAIL_DEBUG = False

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ru'

TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Moscow'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True
```

Я думаю, что ошибка может быть в настройке `nginx`, `gunicorn` или `supervisor`.

**Настройка nginx `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` (проверял с помощью: `sudo nginx -t`):**

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www/<DOMEN>.ru;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name <DOMEN>.ru;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/example.log;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/<USER>/<PROJECT_NAME>;
        expires 30d;
    }

    location /media/ {
        root /home/<USER>/<PROJECT_NAME>;
        expires 30d;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/<USER>/<PROJECT_NAME>/<PROJECT_NAME>.sock;
        proxy_set_header Host $server_name;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
```

**Настройка gunicorn.service `/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service`:**

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=<USER>
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/<USER>/<PROJECT_NAME>
ExecStart=/home/<USER>/venv/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/<USER>/<PROJECT_NAME>/<PROJECT_NAME>.sock <PROJECT_NAME>.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**Настройки supervisor `/etc/supervisor/conf.d`:**

```
[program:<PROGRAM_NAME>]
command=/home/<USER>/venv/bin/gunicorn <PROJECT_NAME>.wsgi:application -c /home/<USER>/<PROJECT_NAME>/config/gunicorn.conf.py
directory=/home/<USER>/<PROJECT_NAME>
user=<USER>
autorestart=true
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile = /home/<USER>/<PROJECT_NAME>/logs/debug.log
```

**Файл `/home/<USER>/<PROJECT_NAME>/config/gunicorn.conf.py`, упомянутый выше, в настройках supervisor `/etc/supervisor/conf.d` во 2-ой строке:**

```
bind = "127.0.0.1:8000"
workers = 3
user = "<USER>"
timeout = 120
```

Файл `/home/<USER>/<PROJECT_NAME>/<PROJECT_NAME>.sock` создаётся, и, как я уже говорил, сервер запускается (проверял с помощью: `sudo systemctl status gunicorn` и `sudo supervisorctl status <PROGRAM_NAME>`)

**В логах `/var/log/nginx/example.log` и `sudo journalctl -u gunicorn`:** пишет `"POST <URL> HTTP/1.0" 500` и дальше что-то типо: `Chrome, Mozilla` и т.д.

**В логах `/home/<USER>/<PROJECT_NAME>/logs/debug.log` и `sudo tail -F /var/log/nginx/error.log`** ничего по этому поводу не нашёл

**Если кто-то знает решение, может сказать, где посмотреть нормальные подробные логи, или дать полезный совет - пишите, буду благодарен за каждую, даже малейшую, помощь. Заранее спасибо**

Comment: Зачем вам одновременно systemd и supervisor?

Comment: Причём в вашей конфигурации, похоже, supervisor никак не используется...

Comment: Спасибо за информацию, но я же сказал, что не эксперт в этом деле. Видимо всё подряд напихал... Но тогда, скорее всего, используется только supervisor, так как я запускаю сайт через ``sudo supervisorctl start all``

Comment: В supervisor вы запускаете gunicorn на порту 8000, но при этом ни одного запроса на него не направляете, поэтому он простаивает без дела и лишь впустую оперативку кушает

Comment: А подробные логи по идее должны быть в `journalctl -u gunicorn`, почему их у вас нет, непонятно

Comment: Можете, пожалуйста, тогда уточнить, что и где мне исправить. В логах ``journalctl -u gunicor`` мне пишет код ошибки и url, больше ничего я не увидел. Ну я пересмотрю, спасибо

Comment: может сделать  DEBUG = True и посмотреть ошибку?

Comment: @ZaArs документация Django делать DEBUG=True на продакшене категорически запрещает

Comment: @andreymal сделать полностью идентичный тестовый сервер и проверить на нем

Comment: @ZaArs но лучше бы как-нибудь выяснить, почему подробные логи отсутствуют)

Answer (score 0):

В общем я решил этот вопрос.

Проблема заключалась в файле send_email:views.py.

Ошибка была следующая:

```
django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ['Значение “2021-06-08 16:27:51.404028 (по времени сервера)” имеет неверный формат. Оно должно быть в формате YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]][TZ].']
```

Я просто исправил соответствующим образом этот файл, и всё заработало.

Большое спасибо за ваши советы. Проблема решена. Всего доброго!